# Apply arbitrary number of OrderBy() in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

I've written an extension method that can take an arbitrary number or OrderBy()'s and apply them recursively....

It's probably best I show an example:

```
public static IEnumerable<User> ApplyOrdering(this IEnumerable<User> users,
                                              int index,
                                              params Func<User, string>[] sorts)
{
    if(index == sorts.Length)
        return users;

    users = users.OrderBy(sorts[index]);
    index++;
    return users.ApplyOrdering(index, sorts);
}

// And it's called like this:
void Example()
{
    var users = GetUnsortedUsers();

    var sortedUsers = users.ApplyOrdering(0, u => u.DisplayName,
                                             u => u.Username,
                                             u => u.Email);
}
```

Not so much a question, but I want to know if this can be done in a better, more elegant fashion?

For one thing, I don't like having to declare the starting index in the method call. Another possible nitpick is having to call .ApplyOrdering() that final time just to return the users.

Whatta 'ya think?! I'd love to see some of the clever solutions you C# gurus out there come up with!

EDIT: I know some of you will point out that it is better, and more expressive to simply write the queries like this:

```
var orderedUsers = users.OrderBy(u => u.DisplayName)
                        .ThenBy(u => u.Username)
                        .ThenBy(u => u.Email);
```

But in my scenario, the amount and type of filters is not always the same, so I needed a general purpose solution that could accomodate any number of filters.

Comment: Why not just chain OrderBy() and ThenBy()?

Comment: IMO, i'd rather use standard LINQ rather than learn a new extension method, it's not much more characters to type.

Comment: If you pass in too many sorts you'll get a..... StackOverflow!!!! (better to use an iterative method)

Comment: @James, George, see edit above

Comment: @ErOx: Understood, thanks for the clarification.  I think Skeet's answer has just what you need :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently it's *broken* - it will effectively apply the ordering *backwards*. I suspect you want:

```
// Slightly more generic, although it's still requiring projections to string...
public static IEnumerable<T> ApplyOrdering<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                              params Func<T, string>[] sorts)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    if (sorts.Length == 0)
    {
        return source;
    }

    IOrderedEnumerable<T> ordered = source.OrderBy(sorts[0]);
    foreach (var ordering in sorts.Skip(1))
    {
        ordered = ordered.ThenBy(ordering);
    }
    return ordered;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work, your list will only be sorted by the last OrderBy you set.

You have to use [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) for the first one, and [ThenBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx) for the others.

Here's what i'd do

```
public static IEnumerable<User> ApplyOrdering(this IEnumerable<User> users, params Func<User, string>[] sorts) 
{     
    var sorted = users.OrderBy(sorts[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < sorts.length; i++)
    {
        sorted = sorted.ThenBy(sorts[i]);
    }
    return sorted; 
}
```

I did not take the time to test my code, and I'm sure there is a better solution.

Comment: Well not quite: it would actually be ordered by email *then* username *then display name. The ordering in LINQ to Objects is stable, so the first ones specified are still relevant - just in the wrong order.

Comment: Lol, yea I guess it can't be edited to work recursively since ThenBy() requires an IOrderedEnumerable. Thanks

Comment: And of course Jon Skeet has a better solution (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts)

Comment: You're incrementing `i` twice per loop iteration.

Comment: Your `ThenBy`s don't do anything. They don't modify the collection they are called on, you have to use their return value. Also, your code wouldn't compile, because `ThenBy` is defined on `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @moi_meme -Great Link! I want to join in the fun... "When Jon Skeet applies thread safety the threads don't feel safe, they feel scared!"

Comment: This code still won't compile: you can't call `ThenBy()` on a variable of type `IEnumerable<T>`, it has to be `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, which is what `OrderBy()` returns.